# Storing list of values in the environment variable in declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I've got the following pipeline but I don't know why it fails on the first line of code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        def mypods = []
    }
    stages {
        stage('Getting pods') {
            steps {
                script {
                   withKubeConfig(caCertificate: '.....', credentialsId: '.....', serverUrl: '.....') {
                       env.mypods = sh "kubectl get pod | grep Running | awk '{print \$1}'"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Print pods') {
            steps {
                script {
                    mypods.each {
                        println "Item: $it"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use a list because the kubectl get pods command return a list of pods, so I have to save and use them during the stages.
How can I create a list on declarative pipeline?
Thanks in advance.

This is the error:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 4: Environment variable values must either be single quoted, double quoted, or function calls. @ line 4, column 22.
           def mypods = []
                        ^

WorkflowScript: 3: No variables specified for environment @ line 3, column 5.
       environment {
       ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:320)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 20):

The declarative pipeline comes with some limitations if it comes to its syntax. You see this error because in the `environment` block you can assign only two types of expressions:

- strings (single or double quoted)
- values returns from function calls

However, you need to be aware that the environment variables store **only** string values, so if you return an array (or any other type from) from the function call, it will be automatically converted to its `toString()` representation.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    environment {
        MYPODS = getPods()
    }

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    println "My pods = ${env.MYPODS}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getPods() {
    return ['pod1', 'pod2']
}
```

Console output:

```sh
[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script (hide)
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
<java.lang.String@ed6c7b35 value=[pod1, pod2] hash=-311657675>
[Pipeline] echo
MYPODS = [pod1, pod2]
[Pipeline] echo
Item: [
[Pipeline] echo
Item: p
[Pipeline] echo
Item: o
[Pipeline] echo
Item: d
[Pipeline] echo
Item: 1
[Pipeline] echo
Item: ,
[Pipeline] echo
Item:  
[Pipeline] echo
Item: p
[Pipeline] echo
Item: o
[Pipeline] echo
Item: d
[Pipeline] echo
Item: 2
[Pipeline] echo
Item: ]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

#### Solution

If you want to store a list of string values then you can define it as a single string of values delimited with `,` character. In this case you can simply tokenize it to a list of values. Consider the following example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 

    environment {
        MYPODS = 'pod1,pod2,pod3'
    }

    stages {
        stage("Test") {
            steps {
                script {
                    MYPODS.tokenize(',').each {
                        println "Item: ${it}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
[Pipeline] node
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Item: pod1
[Pipeline] echo
Item: pod2
[Pipeline] echo
Item: pod3
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your fantastic help! Now, could you please tell me how can I dinamically store, for example, the ls -l | awk '{print $9}' ?Thank you very much!

Comment: This is how I solved the dinamically store into a list:
def getFolders() {
    rootFolder= sh script: "ls -l / | awk '{print \$9}' | sed ':a;N;\$!ba;s/\\n/,/g' | cut -c2-", returnStdout: true    
    return rootFolder
}

Answer (score 0):

You can also you .split(",") function and for-in loop to iterate over.

```
pipeline {
agent any 

environment {
    MYPODS = 'pod1,pod2,pod3'
}

stages {
    stage("Test") {
        steps {
            script {
              for (pod in MYPODS.split(",")) {
                  println("${pod}")
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

your environment should be after the agent

```
pipeline {

agent any
environment {
    def mypods = []
}
stages {
    stage('Getting pods') {
        steps {
            script {
               withKubeConfig(caCertificate: '.....', credentialsId: '.....', serverUrl: '.....') {
                    env.mypods = sh "kubectl get pod | grep Running | awk '{print \$1}'"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Print pods') {
        steps {
            script {
                mypods.each {
                    println "Item: $it"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I've edited my post and my code as you suggested to do! Now you can find the new error. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: can you try [:] instead of [ ] for the array

Comment: This results in error: "Environment variable values must either be single quoted, double quoted, or function calls."