# Jenkins, scripted pipeline: Why echo extra character?

Tags: jenkins

Try to print all list items with below script.

```
node {       
    env.myJobs = [ "abc",
...
            "def"]
    
    stage('Regression') { 
        echo "Test"            
        build_jobs(myJobs)
    }
}

@NonCPS
def build_jobs(list) {
    list.tokenize(',').each { item ->
        echo "${item}"
    }
}
```

Below is build log. For first and last item, it prints extra bracket and add a space to other items.
How to iterate through list without extra character?

```
[Pipeline] echo
[abc
...
[Pipeline] echo
 def]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Szymon Stepniak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676040/storing-list-of-values-in-the-environment-variable-in-declarative-jenkins-pipeli)

1. Define list as a string and seperated with <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>⎵</kbd>
2. Get each item with regex split()

> ```
> node {
>     env.myJobs = 'abc,\
>                  ...
>                  def' 
>    
>     stage('Regression') {
>         echo "Test"
>         build_jobs(myJobs)
>    }
>        
> }
>
> @NonCPS
> def build_jobs(list) {
>    list.split(/, */).each { item ->
>         echo "${item}"
>     } 
> }
> ```